# Call FFmpeg filter from source code (C API)

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encoding, video-capture, decoding

I'm trying to find out how to call a `FFmpeg` filter (`freezedetect`) from within FFmpeg's source code. I see the filter's file is under `libavfilter/vf_freezedetect.c`, but I don't know how to use that filter inside the source code. How can I do that? And what I need to pass to the function?

My FFmpeg command's high-level API is this:

```
ffmpeg -i freeze.mp4 -vf "freezedetect=n=-60dB:d=2" -map 0:v:0 -f null -
```

And what I would need to get the resulting outputs directly after calling a function given its input arguments:

```
lavfi.freezedetect.freeze_start: 5.005
lavfi.freezedetect.freeze_duration: 2.03537
lavfi.freezedetect.freeze_end: 7.04037
lavfi.freezedetect.freeze_start: 13.0464
lavfi.freezedetect.freeze_duration: 3.03637
lavfi.freezedetect.freeze_end: 16.0827
```

Comment: Just for some context, are you already familiar with C programming and the ffmpeg APIs? If not I suggest you start with the dranger.com tutorial on reading and parsing first. If you are comfortable with that, you can ask this question on stackoverflow and I can help with creating pads and filters.

Comment: I am familiar with C, but not FFmpeg C API. Knowing how to call this filter from C API would help.

Comment: Also see `doc/examples` in FFmpeg source code, such as `filtering_video.c`.

Comment: Sure. I hope the answer below can be detailed enough to implement. I'm not super C guy.

Comment: @llogan Is filter API sequential, or multi-threaded? I mean, when calling filters, do they run sequential, not on a separate thread?

Comment: @TinaJ I'm not sure, but you can view the output of `ffmpeg -filters` to see which filters support slice threading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't just call a filter, You must instantiate a filter graph.

First you need to create a `buffer` and `buffersink` via:

```
AVFilterContext* source = 0;
AVFilterContext* sink = 0;
AVFilterGraph *graph = avfilter_graph_alloc()
avfilter_graph_create_filter(&source, avfilter_get_by_name("buffer"), nullptr, args, nullptr, graph);


AVBufferSinkParams* buffersink_params = av_buffersink_params_alloc();
buffersink_params->pixel_fmts = /*Your pixel format HERE*/;

avfilter_graph_create_filter(&sink, avfilter_get_by_name("buffersink"), nullptr, nullptr, buffersink_params, graph);
```

You can then create your filter via something like this

```
snprintf(args, sizeof(args), "n=-60dB:d=2");
avfilter_graph_create_filter(&freezedetect, avfilter_get_by_name("freezedetect"), nullptr, args, nullptr, graph);
```

Then link it all together:

```
avfilter_link(source, 0, freezedetect, 0);
avfilter_link(freezedetect, 0, sink, 0);
avfilter_graph_config(graph, 0);
```

Finally you can send frames to the filter via

```
av_buffersrc_write_frame(source, frame);
```

And get the result with

```
 av_buffersink_get_frame(sink, frame);
```

Don't forget to free it all at the end

Comment: umm looks very promising! And at the same time not easy though. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, Filters are pretty complicated.

Comment: Is filter API sequential, or multi-threaded? I mean, when calling filters, do they run sequential, not on a separate thread?